# Quirky uses of decrementos in for loops for C++

Tags: c++

This was part of a question on a test meant to simply test whether or not we understood the use of decrement operators. I thought I did. I was wrong.

```
for(int i=99; i — -;) 
    cout << i;
```

Why is the first output from this 98!? (According to the test)
I thought the postfix decrement meant that the decrement would occur in the next iteration.

Comment: Prefix vs postfix doesn't change when the check is implemented, it changes the return value of the decrement. The `i--` takes place before the loop is entered. It returns a value of `99`, yes, but then in the body of the loop the decrement has taken place and the first value printed is `98`. Prefix vs postfix is relevant later--it's why the loop eventually prints `0`.

Comment: here, `i--` is the second statement in the for loop and not the third. That's the catch. There's no third statement in the loop

Comment: The question also checks your understanding of loop constructs.   The termination condition of a `for` loop is checked before the loop block is ever executed.

Answer (score 1):

The postfix decrement operator does not mean that the decrement occurs "in the next iteration" of some loop. After all, you will not find any loop in the following function:

```
int counter;

int next_one()
{
    return counter--;
}
```

A very thorough search will not uncover the presence of any loop in the above code. Neither `counter--`, nor anything else, changes its fundamental meaning because it happens to appear as an expression in a `for` loop. `counter--` always means exactly the same thing in C++, wherever it appears. The same applies to any other basic expression.

The postfix decrement operator means that the decrement occurs after its object gets evaluated (its current value "is used"), ***but before the next statement or expression*** (and before a few other sequence points, but that's not germane to this discussion).

```
for(int counter=99; counter--;) 
    cout << counter;
```

In the above code, the "the next statement or expression" that gets executed after `counter--` is `cout << counter`. Therefore, if the counter has an initial value of 99, "before the next statement or expression" gives you an iron-clad guarantee that it will be decremented before `counter`'s value gets printed.

Comment: Thanks, all. This really did clear it up. I suspect I may still get tripped up later on depending on the wording of the question, but for this I'll just have to drill some problems. Cheers!